# How to compare two Sets of objects Not overriding equals/hashCode with Comparator and Streams

Tags: java, java-8, set, java-stream, comparator

I have two `Set`s like the following:

```
Set<Book> s1 = createBooks();
Set<Book> s2 = createBooks(); // or any set of values
```

and this method:

```
private Set<Book> createBooks() {

    List<String> name = Arrays.asList("book 1", "book 2", "book 3");
    List<BookType> type = Arrays.asList(BookType.TYPEONE, BookType.TYPETWO);

    Set<Book> listOfBooks = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setName(name.get(i));
        book.setType(type.get(i));
        listOfBooks.add(books);
    }

    return listOfBooks;
}
```

And this class as well:

```
Class Book {

 private String name;
 private BookType type;

 //here is getter and setter ...

 }
```

I did implement this `Comparator`, but I'm not sure if it's working properly:

```
   Comparator<Book> comparingBooks = (o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) == 0) {
            return o1.getType().compareTo(o2.getType());
        }
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    };


     //I did try this implementation but am not sure it's working as well:

     //Comparator<Book> comparingBooks = Comparator.comparing((Book b)->b.getNName())
              .thenComparing(b->b.getType());
```

An example of the sets when the expected result is `true`:

```
s1 = (new Book("book 1", BookType.ONE), new Book("book 2", BookType.TWO));
s2 = (new Book("book 1", BookType.ONE), new Book("book 2", BookType.TWO));
```

An example of the sets when the expected result is `false`:

```
s1 = (new Book("book 1", BookType.ONE), new Book("book 2", BookType.TWO));     
s2 = (new Book("book 1", BookType.ONE), new Book("book 2", BookType.ONE));
```

I need to compare these sets with something like this:

```
// this flag should validate any difference of Name 
// and Type by returning true, 
// if both Sets have exactly the same objects, 
// it should return false.
boolean compareBooks = s1.stream().anyMatch(a -> s2.stream().anyMatch(b -> comparingBooks.compare(a, b) != 0));
```

I did try this as well but didn't work and always return same value:

```
    boolean compareBooks = SetUtils.isEqualSet(s1, s2);
```

I have no equals and hashcode implementation and can't implement that.

Is there any other way with java 8 and comparator to check and compare these sets?

Comment: You can use `TreeSet` with a custom comparator (instead of `HashSet`) and then `Collections.disjoint()` to detect if there are any common elements.

Comment: Btw, the class the name should reflect the content of a single instance. Use `Book` unless an instance holds multiple books.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for your comment. Would you please provide a coding example with Collctions.disjoint()?
Actually I can't change the name of class it was already set in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A Fix for Comparator

In order to create a `Comparator` in this case you need to provide generic type information explicitly, like that: `<Book, String>comparing()`, where `Book` and `String` are the parameter type and return type of the `Function` that [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) expects as a parameter.

Without an explicit declaration, the compiler has not enough data to determine the type of the variable `book`, and inside both `comparing()` and `thenComparing()` its type will be inferred as `Object`.

```
Comparator<Book> comparingBooks = 
      Comparator.<Book, String>comparing(book -> book.getName())
                           .thenComparing(book -> book.getType());
```

If the case if *only one* of the static methods was used, the **type** of the `book` variable will be correctly inferred by the compiler as `Book` based on the *type of the locale variable* `Comparator<Book> comparingBooks`.

Both method lambda expressions could be replaced with method references:

```
Comparator<Book> comparingBooks =
      Comparator.<Book, String>comparing(Book::getName)
                          .thenComparing(Book::getType);
```

[*for information on the syntax of generic methods, take a look at this tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

[*for more information on how to build comparators with Java 8 methods take a look at this tutorial*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing)

#### Stream

> should validate any difference of Name and Type by returning true, if both Sets have exactly the same objects, it should return false.

Stream `s1.stream().anyMatch(a -> s2.stream().anyMatch(b -> ...))` is currently checking whether there's an element in the first set `s1` that is different from **ANY** of the elements in s2. I.e. the nested `anyMatch()` will return `true` for the first element encountered in ***s1*** that has not matching element in ***s2***. After the comparison of `Book("book 1", BookType.ONE)` (***s1***) with `Book("book 2", BookType.TWO)` (***s2***) `anyMatch()` terminates by returning `true`. And enclosing `anyMatch()` operation propagates this result.

Precisely the same will happen with the second example. The **same pair** of elements differ, although you've changed a type, **names are not equal**. Result is `true`.

**Note:**

- that by convention classes are usually named with *singular nouns*, i.e. `Book` (not *Books*), `Event`, `Person`, etc.
- as a rule of thumb, if your objects are intended to be used with collection they must implement `equals/hashCode` contract, your requirement is very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `TreeSet` using your comparator for equality instead of `equals()`:

```
Set<Books> listOfBooks = new TreeSet<>(comparingBooks);
```

Now you can use standard collection methods to compare the sets:

```
boolean compareBooks = !Collections.disjoint(s1, s2);
```

Comment: thanks, but still it's not working

Comment: I was following the `anyMatch()` logic in your question. If you want to check whether they're the same, just check `s1.equals(s2)`.

Comment: Because the suggested edit queue is full for this answer here is what I suggest to initialize the set :

`List<Book> listOfBooks;
  Comparator<Book> bookComparator = Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle);
  Set<Book> setOfBooks = new TreeSet<>(bookComparator);
  setOfBooks.addAll(listOfBooks);`